# German Business visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, business-travel

I am an Indian citizen living in USA on H1B visa. My visa got expired on 30th Sept 2018. I got my extension approved and I have the physical copy of I-797. Am I eligible to apply for German business visa, or stamping is mandatory to get the same?
My plan is to go to Germany for business need for one week and then from there to India to get the stamping to enter back in USA.

Comment: Which visa expired in September? What do you mean by "stamping"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby In Indian English "stamping" is when the visa is affixed to your passport. It's a holdover from the days when visas were wet ink stamps. Though they aren't actually stamps anymore. And this term is not used by consular staff anywhere. Even so, in this context it still doesn't make sense what he's asking about.